# how to find all the solutions to $I+A+\cdots+A^n=0.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-theory, matrix-equations

Let $GL_3(\mathbb{Z}[i])$ be the group of invertible $3\times 3$ matrices whose coefficients are Gaussian integers.I want to find all the pair $(A\in GL_3(\mathbb{Z}[i]),n\in\mathbb{Z})$ satisfying
$$I+A+\cdots+A^n=0.$$
It is easy to dope out some obvious solutions.Say $(-I,1)$.But how to find all the solutions to this equation?

Comment: Your equation is equivalent to $A^{n+1}=I$ and $A\neq I$.

Comment: This website is for math research, and I'm not certain your question qualifies. A good start can be made, anyway, by multiplying your equation by $I-A$. Finding matrices with $A^m=I$ has a literature.

Comment: [Cross-posted](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634655/how-to-find-all-the-solutions-to-ia-cdotsan-0) to math.stackexchange

Comment: I'm not sure that it's that simple as @lennon310 suggests and that the question does not qualify. As far as I know, **integral** representations of finite cyclic groups are still an open problem. The only hope is the small dimension. I would suggest (but not sure) that there are finitely many conjugacy classes. It is relatively easy to describe them in $GL_3(\mathbb{Q}[i])$, but the passage to $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ may be a bigger problem.

Comment: @Benoît Kloeckner: not quite true: instead of $A^n\ne I$ one should require that $A$ has no invariant vectors.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev: you're right, of course - sorry for being sloppy.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm sorry,Gerry Myerson.I wll be cautious from now on.I also appologize to everyone for my levity.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I'm a young man.I was so eager to solve a problem and needed this lemma.I didn't realize it is unmoral to ask the queation simutaneously on MO and math.stackexchange.I feel ashamed now and will be cautious.Please forgive me.

Comment: @user108005: I have no judgement about cross-posting, but it is something people care to know about. By the way I just posted an answer on MSE.